# react-native-firebase FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fastlane, react-native-firebase

Getting error when trying to compile a react-native project with the react-native-firebase using fastlane and CocoaPods:

```
In file included from /Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXX/XXX/node_modules/react- 
native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/RNFirebaseUtil.h:6:
../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:1:9: fatal error: 
'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
1 error generated.
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this? Facing the same issue

Comment: I changed the lib version to 4.3.8 and added de CocoaPods dependencies:
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1166

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you ran react-native-link or that the library is linked manually.
Try deleting your .XCworkspace folder in your root_Project/ios folder

```
(make sure you have pod 'Firebase/Core' in your podfile and try

rm podfile.lock
pod install
```

If you tried react-native-link and that didn't fix it try to manually link the library yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, here are couple of things that you can try:

1) In **Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings** choose Legacy Build system.

2) Downgrade the **react-native-firebase** package version (this worked for me, i downgraded to **4.1.0**)

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First goto project folder in ios folder and open profile file you just Commit use_framework.

Then delete projectName.xcworkspace, pod folders, and profile.lock file. And pod update, pod install finally open project to xcode and build.